# Reading in attachment via SMTP in C#

Tags: c#, encoding, smtp, base64

I am working on a project where I need to create my own email server with SMTP. All of the SMTP stuff is working fine but I am now working on being able to send attachments.

What I am doing is I am reading the data coming from the client for the attachment which comes in as a base 64 string. I then decode the base 64 string and write that to a file which my email server then attaches and forwards to the recipient.

This is working perfectly when sending a txt file but if I try and send anything else such as a docx, image etc when the decoding happens it throws an exception stating that the base 64 string being invalid length.

When I copy and paste the base 64 string that I receive into an online conversion tool they don't fail by I do get at least part of the correct content as when I look at the image file in notepad++ I see some xml which I can also see in my decoded string on the online conversion tool. However the online tool does have some other stuff which doesn't match.

Is there some difference in the way the base 64 string is encoded when sent to me or is there something  have to do differently with the decoding of the base 64 string between text files and image files.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SMTP has no knowledge of attachments.  It's used to specify a message and a set of recipients.  The recipients need to be valid addresses, but SMTP doesn't really care what the message itself looks like.

What you want to do is research MIME.  MIME is a specific format for e-mail messages that allows you to send messages with rich content (like HTML instead of just plain text) or for sending multi-part messages, such as a message, plus a file attachment.

Sending a message with an attachment will involve constructing an appropriately formatted MIME message, and then using SMTP in the same way you currently do, treating the message as a large body of text, as you would any other.  It's only the special formatting of the text (which is interpreted by mail clients, but ignored by SMTP itself) that makes the difference.

Comment: Well, the SMTP server would accept a multipart message that would include the attachments; so, "nothing to do with attachments" isn't really correct.

Comment: In terms of "How do I do X?", the SMTP server has nothing to do with attachments, or more to the point, it has as much to do with it as a car's engine type has to do with how you pack your clothes in your luggage when you're taking a trip.